# Events triggered on jquery dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Is there a way to have an event triggered when you drag an item to a certain place, or drag it a certain amount?

For example, with a slider you can have an event happen when you drag the slider like this:

```
$( '.slider' ).slider( {
  slide  : function(){},
  change  : function(){}
});
```

is there anything like this with a draggable element using jquery ui?

Comment: Which kind of draggable element are you talking about? If using jQuery UI draggable method, then read the DOC: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it is very simple:

```
$('#id').draggable({
    drag: function(){
        //code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart) out

```
/* events fired on the draggable target */
 element.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {
    //drag code here
 }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you tagged with JQUI so if you are using JQuerUI's [slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change), it has functions for start and change.  If you keep the start number around and compare on each call to change you can get offset of a given pull.

Comment: i was showing that as an example to see if there was a similar thing for a draggable element